# Android Gradle task: connectedInstrumentTest for Release Build?

Tags: android, gradle, automated-tests

Is there any way to run tests against Release build type or any other custom build variant?

The default behaviour of connectedInstrumentTest task is to run tests only against the Debug build variant

Any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

AFAIK `connectedInstrumentTest` runs against the build type specified with the `testBuildType` attribute.
You could try to make this dynamic reading it from the command line arguments:

```
android {
    testBuildType obtainTestBuildType()
}

def obtainTestBuildType() {
    def result = "debug";

    if (project.hasProperty("testBuildType")) {
        result = project.getProperties().get("testBuildType")
    }

    result
}
```

And then call it with

`./gradlew connectedInstrumentTest -PtestBuildType=release`

Comment: Thanks for that. This looks reasonable but the commandline variable looks like it is omitted.  
fyi:I am using buildToolsVersion "19.0.1" gradlew dist (gradle-1.10)

Comment: You are right. Looks like I used a wrong method name, try changing it (see updated answer).

Comment: Great just realised that. Another issue occurred now is that ... when I try to run ./gradlew connectedInstrumentTest -PtestBuildType=release
 
Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{com.example.app.tests/com.example.app.tests.SpoonInstrumentationTestRunner} 

SpoonInstrumentationTestRunner.java lives inside the default instrumentTest directory which not relate to a specific build type

Any ideas will be much appreciated?

Comment: When I tried this with Proguard enabled on my release buildType, the build failed because the `:proguardReleaseTest` task failed due to [**a lot** of warnings](https://gist.github.com/JaKXz/10159871) about classes not being able to find referenced classes. @rciovati any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't you be returning the result from the method?

Comment: ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest -PtestBuildType=release for 2018